# List of generic algorithms and data structures

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

As part of a library project, I want to include a plethora of generic algorithms and data structures. This includes algorithms for searching and sorting, data structures like linked lists and binary trees, path-finding algorithms like A*... the works.

Basically, any generic algorithm or data structure you can think of that you think might be useful in such a library, please post or add it to the list. Thanks! (NOTE: Because there is no single right answer I've of course placed this in community wiki... and also, please don't suggest algorithms which are too specialized to be provided by a generic library)

The List:

- Data structures

  - AVL tree
  - B-tree

    - B*-tree
    - B+-tree
  - Binary tree

    - Binary heap
    - Binary search tree
  - Linked lists

    - Singly linked list
    - Doubly linked list
  - Stack
  - Queue
- Sorting algorithms

  - Binary tree sort
  - Bubble sort
  - Heapsort
  - Insertion sort
  - Merge sort
  - Quicksort
  - Selection sort
- Searching algorithms

Comment: *"I've of course placed this in community wiki"* — No you didn't.

Comment: Forgot to check the box, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Wikipedia?

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms

Answer (score 1):

[Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms), [Data Structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures).

There's already a resource for this sort of material. I'm voting to close as not a real question.